# SSIS expression builder for month

Tags: sql, visual-studio, ssis

i am trying to get a evaluated value of 'Jun2016' in the expression builder in microsoft visual studio for a ssis package.

i have a code

```
(DT_WSTR,4)MONTH( DATEADD( "month", -1, getdate()))
```

which only gives out a value '6'

how can i change it to give me **'Jun'**

Comment: Not 100% sure but try `(DT_WSTR,8)MonthName(DATEADD("month", -1, getdate()), True) + (DT_WSTR,4)YEAR(getdate())`. If you change the Boolean parameter to _False_ it will not abbreviate the month name.

Should that not work, the only other ways I can think of are by building a horrible expression like so: `MONTH(DATEADD("month"), -1, getdate()) == 1 ? "Jan" : MONTH(DATEADD("month"), -1, getdate()) == 2 : "Feb" : ...` or via an Execute SQL Task using `SELECT LEFT(DATENAME(month, DATEADD(...)), 3) + DATENAME(year, DATEADD(...))`

Answer (score 1):

```
(MONTH(DATEADD( "mm", -1, getdate())) == 1 ? "Jan" : MONTH(DATEADD( "mm", -1, getdate())) == 2 ? "Feb" : MONTH(DATEADD( "mm", -1, getdate())) == 3 ? "Mar" : 
     MONTH(DATEADD( "mm", -1, getdate())) == 4 ? "Apr" : MONTH(DATEADD( "mm", -1, getdate())) == 5 ? "May" : MONTH(DATEADD( "mm", -1, getdate())) == 6 ? "Jun" : 
     MONTH(DATEADD( "mm", -1, getdate())) == 7 ? "Jul" : MONTH(DATEADD( "mm", -1, getdate())) == 8 ? "Aug" : MONTH(DATEADD( "mm", -1, getdate())) == 9 ? "Sep" : 
     MONTH(DATEADD( "mm", -1, getdate())) == 10 ? "Oct" : MONTH(DATEADD( "mm", -1, getdate())) == 11 ? "Nov" : MONTH(DATEADD( "mm", -1, getdate())) == 12? "Dec": "")+ 
    RIGHT((DT_WSTR, 4) YEAR( DATEADD( "mm",-1, getdate() )), 4)
```

it should go, removing also the month in the year.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
(MONTH(RowDate) == 1 ? "Jan" : MONTH(RowDate) == 2 ? "Feb" : MONTH(RowDate) == 3 ? "Mar" : 
  MONTH(RowDate) == 4 ? "Apr" : MONTH(RowDate) == 5 ? "May" : MONTH(RowDate) == 6 ? "Jun" : 
  MONTH(RowDate) == 7 ? "Jul" : MONTH(RowDate) == 8 ? "Aug" : MONTH(RowDate) == 9 ? "Sep" : 
  MONTH(RowDate) == 10 ? "Oct" : MONTH(RowDate) == 11 ? "Nov" : MONTH(RowDate) == 12 ? "Dec" : 
  "ERR") + " (" + (DT_WSTR,4)YEAR(RowDate) + ")"
```

http://www.sqlis.com/sqlis/post/Expression-Date-Functions.aspx

Comment: i already look at this before posting, but it doesnt seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

TO Get the YearMonth , we can use below Code if the file name is  FileNameYYYY_MM_DD.xls:

```
(DT_WSTR,4)YEAR(DATEADD( "MM", -1,  (DT_DATE) Replace (SUBSTRING( @[User::FileName]  , FINDSTRING(@[User::FileName], "2017", 1) , 10 ), "_", "-" ))+RIGHT("00"+(DT_WSTR,2)MONTH(DATEADD( "MM", -1,  (DT_DATE) REPLACE(SUBSTRING( @[User::FileName]  , FINDSTRING(@[User::FileName], "2017", 1) , 10 ), "_", "-" )),2)
```